# How to ignore break lines in Javascript with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I have a regular expression to not allow the user inserting special characters like $ # ?.

My expression is this `/^((?![#$%^*<>{}!=|/?])\s.)*$/`

I'm applying it on textarea and when I press ENTER, Angular verify and throws error. I don't want when pressing Enter to see error. Just I want to see the error when the user writes special character.

Does anyone how to modify this regexp? Thanks in advance

I tried to modify the expression but without success.

Comment: You probably just want `/^[^#$%^*<>{}!=|\/?]*$/`

Comment: You don't need to ignore newlines to see if a text includes any of those symbols. Also, remember that if you see an error, [put that error in your post](/help/how-to-ask) and show the code you wrote that triggers that error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to detect one or more symbols in the input, then use:

```js
var input = "Hello World#";  // from your text input field
if (/[#$%^*<>{}!=|/?]/.test(input)) {
    console.log("Symbol found in input.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not want to validate it with regex when you click enter then you might want to use a combination of the `onkeyup` and `onblur` events like,

```
<textarea onkeyup="validateInputWithRegex()" onblur="validateInputWithRegex()" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

By using this, `onkeyup` and `onblur` events will call the `validateInputWithRegex` function whenever a user will type or leave the `textarea`. And the `validateInputWithRegex` will check the textarea content with your regex and accordingly it will show error iff, content contains special char.

```
const validateInputWithRegex = () => {
  const textArea = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
  const errorMessage = document.getElementById('errorMessage');
  const value = textArea.value;
  const regex = /^((?![#$%^*<>{}!=|/?])\s.)*$/;

  if (regex.test(value)) {
    errorMessage.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    errorMessage.innerHTML = 'Error: special characters are not allowed';
  }
};
```